# Difference Between Conditional Distribution and Distribution Parameters

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

Is there any connection between the parameter of a probability distribution and a conditional distribution?

What I am wondering about is, whether or not there is some notational shorthand or implicit mathematical rule that is just not taught, when we, say, calculate the expectation of a normal distribution with parameters $$X  \sim  \mathcal{N} (\mu,\sigma)$$ versus a distribution $$ E[X| M = \mu,\Sigma = \sigma] $$, as we're not using the same formulas for both, but we're conditioning both probability distributions on a scalar value.

I understand that this might be a stupid question, but I cannot find any sources on this on the internet, when I tried to research it myself.